# Wrong priority of maven dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

I have just updated to version 2.7.1 of Spring Boot. While trying to start my application I am receiving bellow error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:449)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:431)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:268)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:246)
    at com.sgdigital.openmarket.catalogue.server.EventCatalogueApp.main(EventCatalogueApp.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.assignableCheckFailed(Assert.java:714)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:645)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:676)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:443)
```

After some searching I found out that in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/dc5acb00191c2eac09907c39e4d890343bf9848d#diff-39eb3613d962cb3e2bfd877c0c20c821c71c8dda9e040c2dd3a2ae8095678b22) CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor stopped implementing ApplicationListener. However in [spring.factories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories#L55) CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor is still listed under EnvironmentPostProcessor and for some reason spring expects it to implement ApplicationListener.

Any ideas on what is going wrong and how to fix it? Could something else cause this conflict? My application was previously on version 2.2.6-RELEASE which is prior to the commit mentioned above.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
After a bit more digging it appears to be an issue with maven dependency priorities. My POM looks like:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

...required stuff

<groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
<artifactId>this-application</artifactId>

<parent>
  <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
  <spring-boot.version>2.7.1</spring-boot.version>
  <some-application.version>1.0.2</some-application.version>

  ...other properties
</properties>

<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  .... more spring dependencies
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-application</artifactId>
    <version>${some-application.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  .... more dependencies

</dependencies>  
...plugins and stuff

</project>
```

"parent" pom contains "spring-boot-starter-web" with version 2.2.6.RELEASE. "some-application" has the same parent pom. I noticed that maven uses "spring-core" from the "spring-boot-starter-web" that is in the "parent" of "some-application" instead of using it from the "spring-boot-starter-web" that is explicitly declared to use 2.7.1.

Running mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose shows it on the proper place:

```
[INFO] com.my.company:this-application:jar:0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.21:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.1:compile - version managed from 2.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile - version managed from 1.7.25; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile - version managed from 1.7.35; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile - version managed from 1.7.35; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.7.1:compile
```

I even tried to use "exclude" tag in the dependency of some-application for spring-core and spring-boot-starter-web with no success. Only thing that seems to work is to explicitly add spring-core as the first dependency of "this-application", but i don't want to do that. Judging from maven documentation this should not happen. Tried building with maven 3.6.3 and 3.8.6.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: You yourself are mixing jars from different versions of Spring and the Spring Cloud version you are using is incompatible with Spring Boot 2.7. So there are actually severl issues.